# Как спарсить все объекты между заданными тэгами?

Tags: c#, парсер

Вот код элемента. На странице их всего 10(следуют друг за другом). Заголовки отличаются по имени класса элемента(в данном случае 781735082462948785). Как создать HtmlElementCollection, в который будут входить все элементы из данного кода? Далее я смогу вытащить нужные мне элементы

```
<div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row listing_781735082462948785" id="listing_sell_new_781735082462948785">

<div class="market_listing_item_img_container">     <img id = "listing_sell_new_781735082462948785_image" src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFAuhqSaKWtEu43mxtbbk6b1a77Twm4Iu8Yl3bCU9Imii1Xt80M5MmD7JZjVLFH-6VnQJQ/62fx62f" srcset="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFAuhqSaKWtEu43mxtbbk6b1a77Twm4Iu8Yl3bCU9Imii1Xt80M5MmD7JZjVLFH-6VnQJQ/62fx62f 1x, https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsUFJ5KBFZv668FFAuhqSaKWtEu43mxtbbk6b1a77Twm4Iu8Yl3bCU9Imii1Xt80M5MmD7JZjVLFH-6VnQJQ/62fx62fdpx2x 2x"" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="" /> </div>
    <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
                <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_action_buttons">
                                <div class="market_listing_buy_button">
                                                <a href = "javascript:BuyMarketListing('listing_sell_new', '781735082462948785', 730, '2', '4392994874')" class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_small">
                            <span>
                                Buy Now</span>
                        </a>
                                        </div>
                        </div>
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
        <span class="market_table_value">
                                                    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
                    1,90 p04430431.                 </span>
                <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_publisher_fee_only">
                    1,82 p04430431.                 </span>
                <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee">
                    1,66 p04430431.                 </span>
                            <br/>
                        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_seller">
    <span class="market_listing_owner_avatar">
        <span class="playerAvatar offline" >
            <img src = "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/11/1132e68e74232da887ee7cc670381339338ea290.jpg" alt="">
        </span>
    </span>
</div>

    <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
    <span id = "listing_sell_new_781735082462948785_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;"><a class="market_listing_item_name_link" href="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Chroma%202%20Case">Chroma 2 Case</a></span>
    <br/>
    <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
</div>
<div style = "clear: both;" ></ div >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь *Html Agility Pack*. С помощью него вы сможете без особых проблем вытащить нужные вам части.

Пример:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.html");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
    att.Value = FixLink(att);
 }
 doc.Save("file.html");
```